# Show Google Maps iFrame from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, google-maps, iframe

I have built a wordpress plugin where users can insert the google map code like this one:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=xxxxx" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

this code is stored in wp-database and I try to get it from inside my angularjs code..

```
getMaps();  
function getMaps(){ 
    $http.post("wp-content/themes/koplan/pages/getMaps.php").success(function(mapsdata){
        $scope.maps = mapsdata;
    });
};
```

My question is: How can I bind/render the iframe in front-end php/html?  I've tried     `<div ng-bind-html=maps>`     but nothing showed up.

Is there anyother way?? Please help me, Thanks

Comment: Why can't you bind? What does it say?

Comment: @trainoasis no warning in console, data (the iframe tag) is viewing if I render with {{}} , but if I render with ng-bind-html the maps still blank.. I just want to convert the iframe tag to view the maps by using angular

Comment: Probably you just have to use trustashtml ?  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#methods_trustashtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you need is [sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#methods_gettrustedhtml) since I guess your iframe is not accepted as a trusted HTML.

So, after including sce into your controller like

```
app.controller("MainController", ['$scope', '$http','$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce){
```

, you would do

```
$scope.maps = $sce.trustAsHtml(mapsdata);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165780/insert-an-iframe-into-page-dynamically-in-angularjs) question/answer also.

Also, for other HTML data that you are sure are 'safe' to display, you can use this filter:

```
app.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
   return function(val) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
   };
});
```

You can use it with

```
ng-bind-html="yourHTMLdataVariable | unsafe"
```

Comment: hey @trainoasis thanks for angularjs documentation , I passed that. and thank you for a link to that case.. thanks for your answer I will try that.

Comment: I have try by your suggestion, and error showed up
    "Error: [$sce:itype] Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html"

I forget that mapsdata was an json.encode.response so that value was an array because it's a more than one maps how do I get fix this problem??

Comment: Did you call trustAsHtml twice on the same variable perhaps? using filter AND inside angular code? You only have to use one of those approaches. Also make sure you passed a string value to trustAsHtml ? use 'typeof' to show variable type. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: thanks for useful answer, btw I'm not using your filter unsafe because I was using that and still not work. The problem is solved by spliting them (`mapsdata`) one by one / convert to string, not an array can `trustAshtml` . only string can so , I split `mapsdata` one by one and not doing `ng-repeat` to view them. Thanks @trainoasis

Comment: hey.. sorry I have a little problem. I think you could help.. you may look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/27517288/4368559